# Python IndexError: string out of range

Tags: python

Hi I'm beginning to learn Python and am stuck on a problem. Here is a segment of my function:

```
for i in range(0,len(list(string))):
    if string[i] in punctuation:
        if i == len(list(string))-1:
             new_string += string[i]
        if string[i+1] or string[i-1] == ' ':
            continue
        elif string[i+1] or string[i-1] in punctuation:
            continue
        else:
            new_string += string[i]

    elif string[i] in numbers:
        new_string += ' '

    else:
        new_string += string[i]
```

This segment is to get a string and return a new_string which takes out all punctuation, but not punctuation that are between letters such as apostrophies (e.g. jacob's) or hypens (e.g. long-established). However, I'm getting an error saying:

```
if doc[i+1] or doc[i-1] == ' ':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I thought that line 3 in my code would prevent that error from happening and I can't see what is wrong. That being said, is my code too inefficient?

Thank you!

Comment: `if` is not `elif`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj: You have some other problem that you've mistakenly blamed on `elif` being gone. It's not gone.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

Comment: `if string[i+1] or string[i-1] == ' ':` must be `if string[i+1]==' ' or string[i-1] == ' ':`.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for the correction. I'm testing my code out with a string like "abc-def" in which the hyphen should be present in the new_string, however it is returning "abcdef" why is this?

Comment: `doc[i-1]` this will refer to the last element if `i==0`.
A string has a len so you don't need to cast it to a list. `len(string)`

Comment: When `i` is at it's final value, of course `[i+1]` is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid an IndexError, it might sometimes be easier to just adapt the range, like so:

```
from string import punctuation as punct

def remove_punctuation(old_string):
    """Remove punctuation from "string" if not between 2 letters."""
    new_string =''
    s = ' ' + old_string + ' '
    for i in range(1, len(s) - 1):
        if s[i] in punct and (not s[i - 1].isalpha() or not s[i + 1].isalpha()):
            continue
        else:
            new_string += s[i]
    return new_string
```